# Load multiple folders containing several jsonl files into a Cloud Database in GCP (e.g.: BigQuery)

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, jsonlines

### Data

The data is formatted as several `.jsonl.gz` files in multiple folders, in a **Google Cloud Storage** bucket.

For example, the files I would load, if I loaded the data file-by-file would be something like:

```
gs://my-bucket/folder1/something1-10.jsonl.gz
gs://my-bucket/folder1/something11-20.jsonl.gz
gs://my-bucket/folder1/something21-30.jsonl.gz
gs://my-bucket/folder2/something1-10.jsonl.gz
gs://my-bucket/folder2/something11-20.jsonl.gz
gs://my-bucket/folder2/something21-30.jsonl.gz
```

These `jsonl` files contents are not different from the usual, meaning its content is something like:

```
{"name": "Foo", "surname": "Loo"}
{"name": "Lauren", "surname": "Impsum"}
...
```

The files individually are not large, but summing all of them, I have a large dataset with a lot more than 500 GB, which would make it quite hard to load in memory, concatenate it into a single file and upload to cloud.

### BigQuery

It seems like [BigQuery allows users to upload data from `jsonl` files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#console), either they are compressed or not. Yet, it does not seem to support reading from multiple files, neither multiple folders.

### Other Tools

I am not restricted to use BigQuery, but I am restricted on using GCP (even if that represents creating a GKE cluster-backed database instance).

Do anyone know how can I handle loading this data into a database?

Answer (score 1):

The [`bq` command line supports loading a set of gzipped JSONL files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#bq) natively.

> You can include a single URI, a comma-separated list of URIs, or a URI
> containing a wildcard.

Try the command

```
bq load \
    --autodetect \
    --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://my-bucket/folder*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) a Google Cloud product for this use case.

In a nutshell, Workflows allows you to connect services together, anything that has a public API. Integrate any Google Cloud API, SaaS API, or private APIs.

You will need to have the following steps defined in Workflow:

- use Cloud Storage API to fetch files from your bucket/folder
- use BigQuery Load API to send the input sourceURIs obtained in first step combining segments from step 2 for your destination name format

There is a full blog post I have about this for CSV files but quickly can be changed to JSON type imports: [Using Cloud Workflows to load Cloud Storage files into BigQuery](https://medium.com/p/54228d166a7d)